# Internet Explorer 6 aborts page request when javascript executes

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6

The scenario is this. A web page contains:

- some DIVs whose visibility can be toggled with a javascript (fired from an hyperlink)
- a Submit button, whose response takes about 5 seconds

The hyperlink code is

```
<a href="javascript:void null;" onclick="MyFunction()">foo</a>
```

The User:

1. Presses Submit.
2. While he is waiting for the response, he clicks on the hyperlink, and fires the javascript that toggles the DIVs visibility (no other request is performed).
3. In Internet Exporer 6, the browser stops waiting for the first Request.

The problem does not happen in other browsers, even if the user plays with the DIVs, the first request is correctly handled, and we navigate to the next page.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Is it a known IE6 issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, this is the **IE6** issue with **GET** requests *triggered from a Javascript action* on a *hyperlink* (**where the href is set to 'javascript:...'**).

> e.g. if your JavaScript calls
>   `someForm.submit()` and the method is
>   `GET`, there will be `NO` response (the
>   request is definately sent though)

http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/09/bug-223-magical-http-get-requests-in.html

You either need to modify the link, to be like:

```
<a href="#bogushash" onclick="MyFunction()">foo</a>
         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

or always set the link with return false;

```
<a href="javascript:void null;" onclick="MyFunction();return false;">foo</a>
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I know that returning false in the onclick prevents the HREF, but I didn't think that a javascript null in the HREF could cause a new Request and abort the real one. Also the page worked absolutely fine until someone modified MyFunction().

Comment: Perhaps you have to inspect the changes to MyFunction() to get an indication of the cause then?

Comment: The *key* is that your function is submitting the form, or changing the location.href, correct?  This is what causes the bug. both workarounds work.

Comment: No. nothing was changing the location or HREF in MyFunction(), just the value of some input fields. Anyway, I changed the href to #foo and return false in my onclick, to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think its wise to call the javascript:void null; from the link.  This may be causing your problem.  Instead have the href contain a valid link but prevent the defaults action from completing the request

```
<a href="#" onclick="return MyFunction(event)">foo</a>
```

where

```
function MyFunction(e)
{
  if (!e) e = window.event;

  // your code

  if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`javascript:void null` should be `javascript:void(0)`, better still is `href="#"`. If MyFunction returns false the `return false` in scunliffe's answer shouldn't be necessary, using `onclick="return MyFunction()"`

Comment: I personally prefer the "#fakelink" syntax as "#" is interpreted as "top" which causes the browser to jump to the top of the screen before unloading the page which can be quite jarring on long pages. #fakelink of course goes nowhere as there is no location with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a problem. I would suggest using a pseudo "loading" spinner that overlays the clickable content when submit is triggered.